# What are "holding numbers" in cycle races?

Tags: terminology, cycling

I just read a tweet where K3 says it is "Holding numbers for pro teams in races around the world." what does that mean can someone help please?

Answer (score 1):

Besides the number on a racer's jersey, professional races often require numbers to be attached to the bicycle frame as well.

[image]
<sub>CC Public Domain from pxhere.com</sub>

K3 sells hardware to clamp the numbers onto professional bike frames.  So that component is "holding" the racer "numbers" on the bike.